# Magento 2.4: How to fix Errors during compilation?

Tags: magento2, error

i have this error after i run the s:d:c command. It show the error happend with my DataProvider and Controller files. HOw to fix this and i really need a suggestions.

```
Errors during compilation:
Rakuten\MemberCard\Model\Config\DataProvider
Incompatible argument type: Required type: string. 
Actual type: \Rakuten\MemberCard\Model\Config\name; File: 
/var/www/html/rakuten_magento/app/code/Rakuten/MemberCard/Model/Config/DataProvider.php

Rakuten\MemberCard\Controller\Adminhtml\Card\Index
Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context. 
Actual type: \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context; File: 
/var/www/html/rakuten_magento/app/code/Rakuten/MemberCard/Controller/Adminhtml/Card/Index.php
```

DataProvider file:

```
<?php

namespace Rakuten\MemberCard\Model\Config;

use Rakuten\MemberCard\Model\CardFactory;
use Rakuten\MemberCard\Model\ResourceModel\Card\CollectionFactory;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected $_loadedData;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected $collection;

    /**
     * DataProvider constructor.
     * @param $name
     * @param $primaryFieldName
     * @param $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->_loadedData)) {
            return $this->_loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $this->_loadedData[$item->getId()] = $item->getData();
        }
        return $this->_loadedData;
    }
}
```

Comment: For second one file you've used `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context` instead of `\Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context`. With first one - please provide file content to determine exact error

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have added the DataProvider content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is related to bad PHPDoc block

You need to update it like

```
    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
```

Comment: That was easy, thank for your help